# How do I migrate my users, groups, and policies to AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I'm having trouble parsing the AWS documentation on migrating existing resources to CloudFormation. My scenario, at least to start with, is that I have:

1. A few IAM users
2. A few groups of which those users are members
3. Several policies attached to each of those groups

How do I create a CloudFormation stack that manages these resources? The paths trough the documentation keep taking me to dead ends where I don't have pieces of the puzzle I need to proceed. But surely this is a common and straightforward scenario, for which it is relatively easy to specify and maintain a stack.

One of the groups (in 2) will always include all of the users (in 1), and my hope is that there's even a way to simply manage (just) that group in such a way that any all of the users (in 1) and then all of the groups of which are members, and then all of the policies attached to any of those groups are included in the stack.

Comment: Instead of using CloudFormation with JSON templates, you can use CDK script.

Comment: @AnkushJain That looks promising, I'd also accept an example of how that works as an answer.

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? You just don't know how to do that in CloudFormation?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I create a CloudFormation stack that manages these resources?

You can't for these IAM resources.  You can [bring certain existing resources into CloudFormation management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) with the Cloudformation [create-change-set](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-change-set.html) `IMPORT` operation.  Alas, IAM Users, Groups, and Policies are not on the list of [resources that support import operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html).

> From the comments: Can a "CDK script" be used for this?

No.  The [CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/home.html) is a powerful abstraction that generates CloudFormation stack templates using a programming language instead of hand-coding the YAML.  There are a few things that the CDK can do that the CloudFormation cannot (and vice versa), but this is not one of them.  @Ankush_Jain may be referring to CDK functionality to get [read-only references](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html#resources_importing) to existing resources. The CDK calls this "importing", but it's not what your looking to do.  Rather, it's functionality to pass existing ARNs and resource names as property settings of new resources.